# do_blocks does not include its CSS

Tags: block-editor

I have a template where I must use the do_blocks function.

It works fine in the HTML sense, but it seems to just not load the CSS related to the block.

Is there a way to force it to load the CSS of the blocks you call with do_blocks?

Comment: Do you mean the stylesheet referenced in the `style` field of your `block.json` file?

Comment: Its better explained here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/40018 (found the issue after this question)